# Why are Folium maps not displayed in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

I want to display a simple map with Folium in Jupyter notebooks.
The code below (and as shown in the picture) should work in Jupyter notebooks, but instead of displaying a map I just get an empty space.

```
# define the world map
world_map = folium.Map()

# display world map
world_map
```

I already tried restarting the kernel and using different browsers (safari, chrome). I also made sure that no content blocker is active. But no difference.

Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to see the map?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any extension installed in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from my friends I managed to find the root cause. The problem were the firewall settings in the router. Some servers, where the folium maps got their data from, were blacklisted. That's why the maps were not displayed.